# customize jQuery-Mask-Plugin

Tags: jquery

I'm using this plugin to do some masking of a ssn # https://github.com/igorescobar/jQuery-Mask-Plugin

I need the result to be `***-**-****`
When the user types I want the previous character to be replaced with *
So if I was typing and I had reached my second character it would look like this. `*2`
I'm trying to use their callback methods. I altered the code slightly to return the pos of the character to be returned in the onChange method.

My code below is not working the way I want it can anyone have a look and help with this. 
Right now it's replacing the character in the incorrect place.

```
  var options =  {
        onComplete: function(cep) {
            console.log('CEP Completed!:' + cep);
        },
        onChange: function(val, pos, e, el, options){

            var newVal;
            var currentPos = pos;
            var lastPos =  currentPos -1;
            if(lastPos != 0){
                newVal = replaceAt(val, lastPos-1, '*');
            }else{
                newVal = val;
            }

            el.val( newVal );
        }
    };

    function replaceAt(s, n, t) {
        return s.substring(0, n) + t + s.substring(n + 1);
    }

    $("#ssn").mask("999-99-9999", options);
```

Comment: Anyone out there that can help with this ?

Comment: The simple answer is to set the type for your input field to 'password'.  The good for this is it will replace any input with bullets.  The bad is that this also means your dash '-' is a bullet.